# Asp.net buttons and checkboxes not visible when application deployed and run through IIS server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, deployment, button

I have web application which perfectly works fine when i run it on local visual studio development server , but the problem is when i deploy the application on IIS server, my asp.net buttons and checkboxes becomes invisible for some reason , can any one help to figure out what exactly is the issue i am facing.

Comment: mahesh ,can you be a bit clear ,where it is disappearing?in VS or in webpage?

Comment: Buttons are not being displayed on the webpage

Comment: If you do a very simple aspx page with just one checkbox and one button on it, does the problem still exist?

Comment: Also, if you do View | Source on the page where the buttons are not displayed, are the checkboxes/buttons there, or are they also absent from the html source? I ask to determine if they are "invisible" or actually not output to the page.

Comment: Ya i can see the source for those buttons when i view it through the firebug, but its not visible on the page

Comment: Click on the button in firebug and then look at the style to see if something is causing it do have display:none or visibility:hidden or something.

Comment: If you're using any stylesheets, make sure that they're up to date and deployed with the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are using "Runat=Server"

[Please find here](http://forums.asp.net/t/874986.aspx/1)

Comment: See his response to my comment above -- the buttons are being output to the page, so this cannot be the problem.